# Why ts file can not play when it contains only one frame?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video file with mp4 format witch can be played very well. And it contains only one frame of video. When I transcode it to TS format. It is black screen when I play it. What can I do to make it perform as mp4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mp4 encodes a duration for each frame, so the player knows how long to keep the frame on screen. Transport streams do not encode a frame duration, the duration is calculated by subtracting a frames time stamp from the next frames time stamp. No next frame, no frame duration. Which means the frame has a duration of zero, and is displayed for zero milliseconds.

What you are asking for is not a feature TS has. You would need to modify the player to change its behavior for zero duration frames.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is really help me a lot to understand TS.